# How to put JVM's manual in windows cli for websphere 8.5

Tags: windows, websphere, windows-server-2008, websphere-8, websphere-7

How to put JVM's in manualmode from windows cli for websphere 8.5
and also how to start/stop jVM clusters from windows CLI.

JVM's are located in servers-->dynamicclusers-->clustername-->memebername

I know scripts are located in C:\websphere\appserver\profiles\appsrv01\bin\startserver.bat

I tried C:\websphere\appserver\profiles\appsrv01\bin\startserver.bat membername

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to start a WebSphere Application Server (WAS) cluster from the command line.  wsadmin is the IBM tool used to provide a command line interface to WAS, it is largely platform agnostic whether you're using Windows, Unix or one of the other supported platforms.  [This IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_startcluster.html) provides a number of ways to management the state of a cluster either by using an mbean or scripts provided by IBM in the installation.